# Create a Fixed-to-bottom navbar in bootstrap that slides content upwards when toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am having two navbars on my website, one in header and other in Footer

Header part working fine, but what i want is that footer should be similar to navbar, but, when i go in mobile view (smaller viewport) there comes a toggle button (default bootstrap feature) but when click on that toggle, it slides downwards, and the content is displayed below the navbar, inspite upwards, so, can anyone help me in this?

I don't know, how to include Bootstrap in Fiddle, so directly posting my footer code. it includes, bootstrap files and Fontawesome files in my directly.

Got [Bootply](http://bootply.com/104001) link:
http://bootply.com/104001

```
<footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer-body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="footer-bar-btns visible-xs">
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="History"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-clock-o blue-text"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Favourites"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-star yellow-text"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Subscriptions"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-rss-square orange-text"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Browse Our Library</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Works for me with bootstrap3 under FF 26.0 & Chrome 31.0.x. What is your target environment (bootstrap & browsers versions) ?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 ! I m running it on latest browsers, except for IE :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by simply changing the order. Instead of putting your navbar-header before your collapse items, put it after. That way you aren't relying on positioning and don't get a flash/jump while the header bar and expand button move to the bottom.

Here's a demo: http://www.bootply.com/117444

All I did was move the collapse items div in front of the "header" div with the button

Comment: How come no results appears when I try viewing bootply? (not the first time I can't see bootply btw)

Comment: @alldani The bootply is working for me, but the issue only appears in mobile because that is when the footer collapses. You should just see a footer at the bottom. I missed it at first as well.

Comment: I see nothing actually.. Only code. But in the result section, nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Fix Skelly solution.

Add one more CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  footer .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #303030;
  }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/4b6cSUMTzg

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the toggle menu to display above instead of under the toggle button. To do that you'd need to absolute position the collaspe menu..

```
footer .navbar-collapse.in {
    bottom: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#333;
    width:100%;
}
```

Bootply Demo: http://bootply.com/103653

Comment: it worked for me ! but the Toggler first slides up with the opened nav and then falls down at the place where i want to be fixed.